# cannot ping specific interface from router: (sendmsg: Operation not permitted)

Tags: iptables, router, ping, arch-linux

I have router that I built running Arch Linux and I have a strange problem that might point to a misconfiguration. Here is my setup:

- LAN interface: intern1
- WAN interface: extern1
- LAN address: 192.168.11.11/24
- WAN address: DHCP

I can ping anything on the WAN interface without error:

```
> ping 8.8.8.8

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=2.78 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=2.60 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=2.87 ms
```

However, I can't ping another address on the LAN (192.168.11.39 is a server on the LAN):

```
> ping 192.168.11.39

PING 192.168.11.39 (192.168.11.39) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.11.11 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
From 192.168.11.11 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
From 192.168.11.11 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

Other questions like this seem to point to a firewall issue. I tried changing all the chains in the filter table to ACCEPT default policy with no effect. I should add that other than this ping issue the router works; things on the LAN can access the WAN and any device on the LAN and ping another device on the LAN.

For the record, I found this issue because I am trying to set up OpenVPN on this router and I can't ping anything on the LAN from any VPN clients. I thought this might be related. Everything here was done without the VPN enabled to eliminate that possibly confounding variable.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

#### Other possibly important information

Routing table:

```
> ip route

default via 45.17.160.1 dev extern1 proto dhcp src 45.17.163.240 metric 1024 
45.17.160.0/22 dev extern1 proto kernel scope link src 45.17.163.240 
45.17.160.1 dev extern1 proto dhcp scope link src 45.17.163.240 metric 1024 
192.168.11.0/24 dev intern1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.11.11
```

iptables rules (minimal example):

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:net_dnat - [0:0]

# potentially DNAT all incoming packets
-A PREROUTING -i extern1 -j net_dnat

# make all LAN-WAN traffic appear as if it came from this router
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.11.0/24 -o extern1 -j MASQUERADE

# make all VPN traffic appear as if it came from this router
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o intern1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o extern1 -j MASQUERADE

# DNAT table for port forwards on LAN
-A net_dnat -m comment --comment "SSH" -p tcp -m tcp --dport 39022 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.39:39022
-A net_dnat -m comment --comment "HTTP" -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.39:80
-A net_dnat -m comment --comment "HTTPS" -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.39:443
-A net_dnat -m comment --comment "IMAP" -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.39:143
-A net_dnat -m comment --comment "IMAPS" -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.39:993
-A net_dnat -m comment --comment "WOL" -p udp -m udp --dport 39009 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.254:39009
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

systemd-networkd configuration:

```
> cat /etc/systemd/network/intern1.network

[Match]
Name=intern1

[Network]
Address=192.168.11.11/24
IPForward=ipv4

> cat /etc/systemd/network/intern1.network

[Match]
Name=extern1

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
IPForward=ipv4
```

#### Edit 1

routing policy:

```
> ip rule ls
0:     from all lookup local
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
```

ARP entry for 192.168.11.39:

```
> ip n ls 192.168.11.39
192.168.11.39 dev intern1 lladdr f8:32:e4:9b:b9:55 REACHABLE
```

Route lookup for 192.168.11.39:

```
> ip route get 192.168.11.39
192.168.11.39 dev intern1 src 192.168.11.11 uid 1000 
    cache
```

#### Edit 2

full filter table:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:localhost-LAN - [0:0]
:localhost-WAN - [0:0]
:localhost-VPN - [0:0]
:VPN-localhost - [0:0]
:LAN-localhost - [0:0]
:WAN-localhost - [0:0]
:LAN-VPN - [0:0]
:LAN-WAN - [0:0]
:WAN-LAN - [0:0]
:WAN-VPN - [0:0]
:LAN-forward - [0:0]
:WAN-forward - [0:0]
:VPN-forward - [0:0]
:reject - [0:0]

-A INPUT -i intern1 -j LAN-localhost
-A INPUT -i extern1 -j WAN-localhost
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j VPN-localhost
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -g reject

-A FORWARD -i extern1 -j WAN-forward
-A FORWARD -i intern1 -j LAN-forward
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -j VPN-forward
-A FORWARD -g reject

-A OUTPUT -o extern1 -j localhost-WAN
-A OUTPUT -o intern1 -j localhost-LAN
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j localhost-VPN
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -g reject

-A LAN-forward -o extern1 -j ACCEPT
-A LAN-forward -o tun0 -j LAN-VPN

-A WAN-forward -o intern1 -j WAN-LAN
-A WAN-forward -o tun0 -j WAN-VPN

-A VPN-forward -o intern1 -j ACCEPT
-A VPN-forward -o extern1 -j ACCEPT

-A WAN-LAN -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-LAN -m comment --comment "SSH" -d 192.168.11.39/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 39022 -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 39022 -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-LAN -m comment --comment "HTTP" -d 192.168.11.39/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-LAN -m comment --comment "HTTPS" -d 192.168.11.39/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-LAN -m comment --comment "IMAP" -d 192.168.11.39/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-LAN -m comment --comment "IMAPS" -d 192.168.11.39/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-LAN -m comment --comment "WOL" -d 192.168.11.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 39009 -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 39009 -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-LAN -j DROP

-A localhost-LAN -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A localhost-LAN -m comment --comment "Local DHCP" -p udp -m udp --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
-A localhost-LAN -m comment --comment "Local SSH" -d 192.168.11.39/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 39022 -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 39022 -j ACCEPT
-A localhost-LAN -g reject

-A LAN-VPN -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LAN-VPN -j DROP

-A WAN-VPN -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-VPN -j DROP

-A localhost-VPN -j ACCEPT

-A localhost-WAN -j ACCEPT

-A LAN-localhost -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LAN-localhost -m comment --comment "LAN OpenVPN" -p udp --dport 21194 -j ACCEPT
-A LAN-localhost -m comment --comment "LAN DHCP" -p udp -m udp --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
-A LAN-localhost -m comment --comment "LAN SSH" -p tcp --dport 29022 -j ACCEPT
-A LAN-localhost -m comment --comment "LAN DNS (zone transfer)" -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LAN-localhost -m comment --comment "LAN DNS" -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LAN-localhost -m comment --comment "LAN Ping" -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A LAN-localhost -g reject

-A WAN-localhost -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-localhost -m comment --comment "WAN OpenVPN" -p udp --dport 21194 -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-localhost -m comment --comment "WAN SSH" -p tcp --dport 29022 -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-localhost -m comment --comment "WAN Ping" -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A WAN-localhost -j DROP

-A VPN-localhost -j ACCEPT

-A reject -m addrtype --src-type BROADCAST -j DROP
-A reject -s 224.0.0.0/4 -j DROP
-A reject -p igmp -j DROP
-A reject -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A reject -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A reject -p icmp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
-A reject -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Comment: Please show output of commands: `ip rule ls` and `ip route get 192.168.11.39` and `ip n ls to 192.168.11.39`.

Comment: thanks, added those commands and outputs

Comment: Hm. Very strange. Have you provided the full output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: @AntonDanilov nope, I excluded everything except the INPUT/OUTPUT/FORWARD chains in the filter table since I thought using 'ACCEPT' as the default policy would nullify everything else and therefore I wouldn't need to include the the gory/possibly irrelevant details of the filter table in the OP. I figured out this was the wrong assumption, which led to the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

It actually was a firewall problem. I incorrectly assumed that using ACCEPT as default policy on the 'INPUT/OUTPUT/FORWARD' chains would nullify all the remaining chains in the filter table, which made me think this wasn't a firewall issue in the first place

In reality the default policy is applied last when nothing matches, but in this case the 'localhost-LAN' chain was intercepting the outgoing ping and applying 'reject'. Adding this before the 'reject' target fixed the issue:

```
-A localhost-LAN -m comment --comment "LAN Ping" -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

Outgoing ping to LAN now works :)